# Amazon EC2 How Do I Host My Own Content on a Bitnami-Wordpress Instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I created an instance to host my wordpress blog. I made a keypair, converted it using PuTTY Gen so that it would work with winscp.

My security group that is associated with my instance has:

> ICMP Allow All 
>   TCP 0-65535 
>   TCP 22 (SSH) 
>   TCP 80 (HTTP) 
>   TCP 443 (HTTPS) 
>   UDP 0-65535

I am running a **Bitnami-Wordpress 3.2.1-0 Ubuntu AMI**

---

**My Question is: How do I host a simple file on my instance?**

---

UPDATE: so I was able to login using SFTP by simply filling in my instance Public DNS as my host, and the PuTTY Gen key as the private key, the username I had to use was Bitnami. So now I have access to the server, how or where do I put a file so that it will come out www.mywebsite.com/myfile.file???

I am assuming that I need to SSH into the server using putty, and add it into the WWW directoroy?

What I have tried:

I tried logging in using WinSCP with host name being my instance's Public DNS, and my private key file the converted PuTTY Gen file that was originally the key pair for the instance.

1. Using SFTP, pressing login it asks me for a user name, entering "user" or "ec2-user" I get an error saying:

   > "disconnected, no supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key), Server >refused our key. Authentication failed.

   Using root for the username, it asks for a passphrase that I created for my keypair using PuTTY Gen, It accepts it, but then I get this error:

   > "Received too large (1349281121 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 1024000 B. The error >is typically caused by message printed from startup script (like .profile). The message may start >with ""Plea"". Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running a SFTP server?

If in WinSCP I put the username as "user" and the password as "bitnami" (before I press login) (default wordpress password for bitnami AMI) it gives me this error:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey). Authentication log (see session log for details):Using username: "user". Server refused ourkey. Authentication failed.

1. I get the same errors using SCP instead of SFTP in WinSCP except when I use SCP and I press login, and I use username "root" it asks me for my passphrase, after entering that I get this error:

> Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit status 0. Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended).

Answer (score 1):

If you are already able to connect using SFTP. Now you just need to copy the file. Where you need to copy it depend on what you are trying to do.

BitNami Wordpress AMI has the following directory structure (I only include the relevant directories for this question):

```
/opt/bitnami
        |
        |-- apache2/htdocs
        |-- apps/wordpress/htdocs
```

You mentioned that you want to www.mywebsite.com/myfile.file. If you didn't modify the default apache configuration you will need to copy file in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs (this is the DocumentRoot for the BitNami WordPress AMI.

If you want that file to be accessed from www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/myfile.file, then you need to copy it in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs.

If what you are trying to do is to manually install a theme or plugin you can follow the WordPress documentation taking into account that the wordpress installation directory is /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs.

Also, you can find below some links to the BitNami Wiki explaining how to connect to the AMIs. I just include them as a reference for other users that find the same connection issues.

Further reading:

- [How to connect to your amazon instance](http://wiki.bitnami.org/cloud/how_to_connect_to_your_amazon_instance)
- [How to upload files from Windows](http://wiki.bitnami.org/BitNami_Hosting/FAQ#How_to_upload_files_to_the_server_from_Windows_machine.3f)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to remove wordpress from the URL, you can use the following instructions I posted on my blog ([travisnelson.net](http://travisnelson.net)):

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
$ vi /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

changed DocumentRoot to be:  DocumentRoot “/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs”

```
$ sudo chmod 544 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
$ sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Then in WordPress, change the Site address (URL) in General Settings to not have /wordpress.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently.  Having setup Bitnami Wordpress on AmazonAWS I was unable to modify, add, or remove themes from within the Wordpress admin interface even though all of my permissions were setup appropriately according to Wordpress recommended settings.  However, I did not want to have to resort to turning FTP access on.

I was able to resolve the issue by:

1. Setting the file access method for Bitnami Wordpress to 'direct'.
2. Changing all users to Apache Bitnami.
3. Adding Bitnami to Apache group and Apache to Bitnami group.